# CodeIgniter APC Cache fails to GET

Tags: codeigniter, caching, fetch, apc

I've searched the *entire* Internet and cannot solve why my cache GET in CodeIgniter 3 doesn't work.

This function, with ADD and GET living together in sin, **works as expected** and displays the cache after GETing it:

```
public function apc_add_and_get()
  {
    # load Cache driver using APC, failover to file caching, and prefix the cache
    $this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'apc', 'backup' => 'file', 'key_prefix' => ''));

    $data = array(
      'CI Admins' => array(
        'CI Admin' => array(
          'name' => 'John',
          'site' => 'https://www.example.com'
        )
      ), 
      'CI users' => array(
        'CI user' => array(
          'name' => 'Sally',
          'site' => 'https://www.another.com'
        )
      ),    
    );

    // Save into the cache for 5 minutes
    $this->cache->save('foo', $data, 300);

    echo '<p><pre>';
    var_dump($this->cache->get('foo')); // get the cache entry named 'foo'
    echo '</pre></p>';
  }
```

Why, when I split the ADD and GET into **separate** functions shown below, does the **GET** return FALSE?

```
public function apc_add()
  {
    # load Cache driver using APC, failover to file caching, and prefix the cache
    $this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'apc', 'backup' => 'file', 'key_prefix' => ''));

    $data = array(
      'CI Admins' => array(
        'CI Admin' => array(
          'name' => 'John',
          'site' => 'https://www.example.com'
        )
      ), 
      'CI users' => array(
        'CI user' => array(
          'name' => 'Sally',
          'site' => 'https://www.another.com'
        )
      ),    
    );

    // Save into the cache for 5 minutes
    $this->cache->save('foo', $data, 300);

  }

public function apc_get()
  {
    # load Cache driver using APC, failover to file caching, and prefix the cache
    $this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'apc', 'backup' => 'file', 'key_prefix' => ''));

    echo '<p><pre>';
    var_dump($this->cache->get('foo')); // get the cache entry named 'foo'
    echo '</pre></p>';
  }
```

Neither the server error log nor the CodeIgniter error log show any problems.

**The goal** is to save a large set of constants to the cache. As the program is run after that, it would retrieve the values from the cache. So, I would call the ADD function once to create the cache and each time the program is run subsequently, I would call the GET function.

(Doing this would save my three users *milliseconds per year*; that's why I've spent more than *10 hours* on this :-))

My sanity awaits your most excellent suggestions!

VITAL STATS:

```
    CodeIgniter 3.1.5
    GoDaddy shared Linux hosting
    PHP 5.3.24
    APC is enabled
```

CodeIgniter manual page: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html

Comment: you would've more to gain if you update php 5.3 to php 7 or 5.6 ;)
besides of that - how do you call apc_get and apc_add ?

Comment: I call it via the browser:  www.mywebsite.com/index.php/home/apc_add

where /home is the controller and /apc_add is the method.